# When load component from dfm file build without runtime-package, EClassNotFound error problem

Tags: delphi

I made some custom component with Delphi XE5:

```
    TMyPanel = class(TPanel)
      ...
    end;

    TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
      ...
    end;

    procedure Register;

implementation

  procedure Register;
  begin
    RegisterComponents('MyComp', [TMyPanel,TMyComponent]);
  end;
  
  ...

initialization
  RegisterClasses([TMyPanel,TMyComponent]);
  ...
```

And build to "mycomp.bpl' file and install the component.

In my application, load the bpl file like :

`FPkgHande := LoadPackage('mycomp.bpl');`

Then made "mydfm.dfm" file with above components using Twriter.WriteComponent(...).

And tried to load dfm file like below:

```
        ...
  var
    Reader: TReader;
  begin
       ...
    Reader.ReadComponent(ParentControl);
       ...
  end;
```

When my application build with runtime package as below:

`Project->Options->Packages->Runtime Packages->Link with runtime packages = True`

It can be loaded dfm file to form successfully.

But when set to False my application option as below:

`Project->Options->Packages->Runtime Packages->Link with runtime packages = False`

then my application got an error like:

`"...TMyComponent class not found..."`

What is the cause of this error?

Comment: Why not install your component in the IDE and use it as any other component without all that complexity you add?

Comment: Simply, you can’t. When you want to use dynamic packages, you need to compile the project with runtime packages ‘true’.

Comment: Building with runtime packages means that your module has enough RTTI information for the dependent packages to be able to perform dfm serialization.

Comment: When runtime packages are enabled, your EXE and BPL will share a single instance of the RTL, which allows registrations and RTTI to be shared. But when you disable runtime packages, the EXE and BPL will use separate instances of the RTL, thus the error because registrations made by the BPL's RTL won't be seen be the EXE's RTL.